# Angular ngAnimate,ng-view leave animation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate, gsap

angular version: 1.6.1

I'm trying to make a fade in/out for my ng-view element. The problem is that only the enter animation works.

html part:

```
<main class="main" ng-view></main>
```

app.js

```
App.animation('.main', function() {
        return {
            enter : function(element, done) {
                TweenMax.set(element,{autoAlpha:0});
                TweenMax.to(element, .4, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Quad.easeOut, delay: 1});
                done();
            },

            leave : function(element, done) {
                TweenMax.to(element, .4, {autoAlpha: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut});
                done();
            }
        };
    });
```

Thanks in advance, i appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
            enter : function(element, done) {

                TweenMax.to(element, .4, {autoAlpha: 1, ease: Quad.easeOut, delay: 1, onComplete:done});

            },

            leave : function(element, done) {
                TweenMax.to(element, .4, {autoAlpha: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut, onComplete:done});

            }
```

css || .main: opacity: 0;